# I have been getting "Failed to write to 'index.js'. Please try again." whenever I try to update my lambda function code. why am I facing this issue?

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have been getting "Failed to write to 'index.js'. Please try again." whenever I try to update my lambda function code. I tried recreating the function again but to no avail, why am I facing this issue with aws. I am getting the same error for both EU Ireland and US N.Virginia. I am simply not able to create my lambda function from the aws console. It has happened for the first time. I was using it in the morning, all was right. Then in noon strangely it started behaving like it. I cannot make a new function.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This rather seems like some temporary bug or problem in Chrome and viewing the page in other browsers like Firefox, Opera etc. will allow you to save the lambda function.

Comment: it is surely not temporary, still facing the same issue in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Even, I had the same the same error occurring in Chrome Browser. When opened the same page in Incognito Mode, it was working.

So, I switched back to my original chrome tab and then cleared cache. After that, I did not get the error. Hope this will solve any such problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I had a return statement that wasn't returning anything. Just `return` on a line by itself, in node 6. I removed it because it was the end of the function anyway, and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Works on firefox, not on chrome or opera